# Regex To Exclude Email-Expression

Tags: html, regex, email, notepad++, extract

I have 430 HTML files of different organization's contact us web pages, I was given this files to extract emails from.

**This regex simple code I came up with detects and finds emails throughout the files**

```
\S*@\S*
```

**My Problem**

I'm trying to select everything besides the emails so I can use Notepad++'s "Replace All in All Opened Documents" function to delete everything besides the emails. Is this possible with regular expressions?

Is there anyway I can select everything outside of the regular expression provided above?

Comment: *Find what*: `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)|.`.
*Replace with*: `$1`. Then, you might want to use *Edit -> Blank Operations -> Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL* menu option.

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). [Rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is also cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a recent version of Notepad++ installed to have the necessary regex support:

**Find what :** `(^|\s+)[^@]+(\s+|$)`
**Replace with :** `\n`
 **Regular expression**

The  **`.` matches newline** option does not influence the action.

Comment: *`.` matches newline* is redundant here as your pattern does not contain the dot.

Comment: Indeed, whether it is set or not does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all text that does not match some pattern.

You need to match and capture the emails with a `(...)` *capture group* and then you need to *just match* everything else.

Use a pattern like this: `(` + `your_pattern` + `)|.`, and replace with `$1`.

Or, use:

```
([^\s<>"]+@[^\s<>"]+)|.
```

or

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)|.
```

Replace with: `$1`

Then, you might want to use *Edit* -> *Blank Operations* -> *Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL* menu option.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, a common way to say thanks on SO is *upvoting* the answer that turned out helpful.